# Inline css image reference in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates

I passed `context_object_name = 'project'` in template and I need this:

```
<div style="background-image: url( {{ project.thumbnail.url}}  )"></div>
```

but above line doesn't work. However, `<img src="{{ project.thumbnail.url }}" alt="thumb" />` works fine.

What is the solution? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with the way you did, you are just missing the width and height attributes

this one works for me:

```
<div style="background-image: url( {{project.thumbnail.url}}  ); width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
```

Comment: exactly, I defined those width and height  in css. sounds  like it has been overwritten. This one made it. Thanks

Comment: Glad that it helped. You can either do <div style="background: url({{project.thumbnail.url}}); background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 500px 500px"> fill it here <br> <br> it will display the background with content </div>